# How can I float two tables next to each other left to right and center them both?

Tags: html, css

I have two tables, which I would like to position next to each other BUT want them to be on the center of the page.

I almost did it, I only have a problem how to align them on the center of the page. My example:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tps7N/146/)**

My HTML:

```
<table class="table_on_the_left">
    <tr><td>
        hello demo here 
        </td></tr></table>

<table class="table_on_the_right">
    <tr><td>
        hello demo here 2 
    </td></tr></table>
```

My CSS:

```
table.table_on_the_left {
    position:center;
    float:left;
   }

  table.table_on_the_right {
    position:center;
    float:right;
  }
```

Comment: There is no center position, `position:center;`.

Comment: Why are you using tables, is it tabular data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to use `inline-block` instead of `float`:

```
table.table_on_the_left, table.table_on_the_right {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

And to make the horizontal align `text-align:center` on the parent:

```
body {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Check this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tps7N/150/)**

<sub>[**Here you can know more about inline-block**](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)</sub>

Aside a recommendation plus if you are trying to set the layout for your page avoid to use `<table>` save it only for tabular data and instead use `<div>` and positioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap them in a div and use that to make them sit next to eachother and center them.

### HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <table class="table_on_the_left">
        <tr>
            <td>hello demo here</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="table_on_the_right">
        <tr>
            <td>hello demo here 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
table.table_on_the_left {
    position:center;
    float:left;
}
table.table_on_the_right {
    position:center;
    float:right;
}
#wrap {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/Tps7N/151/)